# Macbook Pro random shutdowns (AppleThunderboltNHI.kext and IOThunderboltFamily.kext fix for 10.15.5?)

Tags: kernel-panic, kernel-extensions

I've got a mid-2014 Macbook Pro that suffers from frequent random shutdowns. The screen will turn black while the backlight remains on, the fans will usually spin up, and then after a couple of seconds it'll power down. The shutdowns will occur within the first 30 minutes of use, becoming more frequent after each subsequent reboot - occurring every 5 minutes or so after a couple of restarts.

This issue has been covered and solved previously: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/433516/MacBook+Pro+Shuts+down+randomly

However, previous fixes (removing and/or renaming AppleThunderboltNHI.kext and/or IOThungerboltFamily.kext) do not appear to be effective at solving the problem on systems running Catalina 10.15.5